# Машинное обучение. Классификация. Ошибка при использовании модели

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn, классификация

Участвую в соревновании Titanic: Machine Learning from Disaster на Kaggle. Мой kernel работал, но внезапно стали вываливаться ошибки для методов Random Forest и Gradient Boosting Classifier, каких-либо особых изменений не припомню.

```
X_train = train_df
Y_train = targets
X_test  = test_df.copy()
X_train.shape, Y_train.shape, X_test.shape

Результат:
((891, 14), (891,), (418, 14))

# Random Forest
 rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=350)
 rf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
 Y_pred = random_forest.predict(X_test)
 rf.score(X_train, Y_train)
 acc_random_forest = round(random_forest.score(X_train, Y_train) * 100, 2)
 acc_random_forest

 # Gradient Boosting Classifier
 gb = GradientBoostingClassifier()
 gb.fit(X_train, Y_train)
 Y_pred = gbk.predict(X_test)
 acc_gbk = round(gbk.score(X_train, Y_train) * 100, 2)
 acc_gbk
```

Ошибка:

> ```
> ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input.
> Model  n_features is 12 and input n_features is 14
> ```

Был бы очень благодарен, если кто-то сможет подсказать, в чем может быть проблема. При необходимости могу дать ссылку на ядро, предоставить другие данные.

Comment: лучше дать ссылку на kernel... Какая из двух моделей выдает ошибку - RandomForest? Можете вывести размерности `X_train.shape`, `Y_train.shape` непосредственно перед `rf.fit(X_train, Y_train)` и перед `gb.fit(X_train, Y_train)`?

Comment: @MaxU, Logistic Regression, K-Nearest Neighbours, Support Vector Machines, Gaussian Naive Bayes, Decision Tree - работают.
Представленные в вопросе - нет.

Размерности выводил непосредственно перед использованием.

Ссылка на kernel: https://www.kaggle.com/distherion/titanic-prediction

Comment: @MaxU, вывел размерности и информацию о датасетах непосредственно использованием. Судя по ошибке, размерности X_train и X_test не совпадают, но ведь это не так...

Comment: в вашем kernel вы обучаете объект `rf`, а предсказываете используя объект `random_forest`, который нигде не объявлен?? Да и ошибки из вопроса я в kernel не увидел

Comment: @MaxU, наиглупейшая ошибка, все заработало. Огромное спасибо, видимо, от усталости не замечаю уже ничего! Оформляйте как ответ, поставлю плюсик. Ошибка выводилась именно та, что в вопросе, могу обратно поменять и скрин сделать, но вряд ли это нужно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В следующем блоке кода:

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=350)
rf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
Y_pred = random_forest.predict(X_test)
```

обучается объект `rf`, а для предсказания используется объект `random_forest`, который нигде не объявлен.

Попробуйте заменить `random_forest` на `rf`.